# Can't update rspec-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bundler

When I run `bundle outdated` I get:

```
Outdated gems included in the bundle:
  * airbrake (newest 5.2.2, installed 4.3.6, requested ~> 4.3.4) in group "default"
  * jquery-rails (newest 4.1.1, installed 4.1.0) in group "default"
  * rspec-rails (newest 3.4.2, installed 3.1.0) in group "test"
  * autoprefixer-rails (newest 6.3.4, installed 6.3.1)
  * coderay (newest 1.1.1, installed 1.1.0)
  * has_scope (newest 0.7.0, installed 0.6.0)
  * jwt (newest 1.5.3, installed 1.5.1)
  * mail (newest 2.6.4, installed 2.6.3)
  * mime-types (newest 3.0, installed 2.99.1)
  * mimemagic (newest 0.3.1, installed 0.3.0)
  * mini_portile2 (newest 2.1.0, installed 2.0.0)
  * net-ssh (newest 3.1.1, installed 3.0.2)
  * rspec-core (newest 3.4.4, installed 3.1.7)
  * rspec-expectations (newest 3.4.0, installed 3.1.2)
  * rspec-mocks (newest 3.4.1, installed 3.1.3)
  * rspec-support (newest 3.4.1, installed 3.1.2)
  * sprockets-rails (newest 3.0.4, installed 3.0.3)
  * sshkit (newest 1.9.0, installed 1.8.1)
```

I wanted to update `rspec-rails` with `bundle update rspec-rails` but the version is still 3.1.0.

Why?

I also tried:

```
bundle update rspec-core rspec-expectations rspec-mocks rspec-support rspec-rails
```

It didn't help.

My Gemfile:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Core
gem 'rails', '5.0.0.beta3'
gem 'pg'
gem 'redis'
gem 'puma'
gem 'config'

# Assets
gem 'uglifier'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'slim-rails'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'

# Other
gem 'paperclip'
gem 'devise', '4.0.0.rc2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'airbrake', '~> 4.3.4'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', github: 'mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'kaminari', github: 'amatsuda/kaminari', branch: '0-17-stable'

group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'simplecov', require: false
end

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.4'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'rubocop'
end
```

Gemfile.lock:

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin.git
  revision: 8b80ddad36bd1ba8ab0bb9ac8593d409e0fcbbf9
  specs:
    activeadmin (1.0.0.pre2)
      arbre (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      bourbon
      coffee-rails
      formtastic (~> 3.1)
      formtastic_i18n
      inherited_resources (~> 1.6)
      jquery-rails
      jquery-ui-rails
      kaminari (~> 0.15)
      rails (>= 3.2, < 5.0)
      ransack (~> 1.3)
      sass-rails
      sprockets (< 4)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari.git
  revision: 1002b14aee62d4360c383ae1f14f5b5b72e76e2a
  branch: 0-17-stable
  specs:
    kaminari (0.17.0.alpha)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on.git
  revision: dde41a4d0d14e0f5b57c685265f68545383f70fa
  specs:
    acts-as-taggable-on (3.5.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.2, < 5)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.0.0.beta3)
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      nio4r (~> 1.2)
      websocket-driver (~> 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.0.0.beta3)
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      actionview (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      activejob (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
    actionpack (5.0.0.beta3)
      actionview (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      rack (~> 2.x)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.0.0.beta3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.5)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    activejob (5.0.0.beta3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.0.0.beta3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.beta3)
    activerecord (5.0.0.beta3)
      activemodel (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      arel (~> 7.0)
    activesupport (5.0.0.beta3)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    airbrake (4.3.6)
      builder
      multi_json
    arbre (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    arel (7.0.0)
    ast (2.2.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (6.3.1)
      execjs
      json
    awesome_print (1.6.1)
    bcrypt (3.1.11)
    better_errors (2.1.1)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubis (>= 2.6.6)
      rack (>= 0.9.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.2)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.6)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sass (>= 3.3.4)
    bourbon (4.2.6)
      sass (~> 3.4)
      thor (~> 0.19)
    builder (3.2.2)
    byebug (8.2.2)
    capistrano (3.4.0)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.3)
    capistrano-bundler (1.1.4)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano-rails (1.1.6)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (~> 1.1)
    capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    climate_control (0.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
    cocaine (0.5.8)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coderay (1.1.0)
    coffee-rails (4.1.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.1.x)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.1)
    config (1.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      deep_merge (~> 1.0.1)
    database_cleaner (1.5.1)
    debug_inspector (0.0.2)
    deep_merge (1.0.1)
    devise (4.0.0.rc2)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0, < 5.1)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    diff-lcs (1.2.5)
    docile (1.1.5)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.6.0)
    factory_girl (4.5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.6.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.5.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faraday (0.9.2)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    formtastic (3.1.3)
      actionpack (>= 3.2.13)
    formtastic_i18n (0.6.0)
    globalid (0.3.6)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
    has_scope (0.6.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.2, < 5)
      activesupport (>= 3.2, < 5)
    hashie (3.4.3)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    inherited_resources (1.6.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.2, < 5)
      has_scope (~> 0.6.0.rc)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 5)
      responders
    jquery-rails (4.1.0)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 1.0)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.3)
    jwt (1.5.1)
    loofah (2.0.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.6.3)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    method_source (0.8.2)
    mime-types (2.99.1)
    mimemagic (0.3.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.0.0)
    minitest (5.8.4)
    multi_json (1.11.2)
    multi_xml (0.5.5)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (3.0.2)
    nio4r (1.2.1)
    nokogiri (1.6.7.2)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.0.0.rc2)
    oauth2 (1.1.0)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.10)
      jwt (~> 1.0, < 1.5.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (>= 1.2, < 3)
    omniauth (1.3.1)
      hashie (>= 1.2, < 4)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    omniauth-facebook (3.0.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.4.0)
      oauth2 (~> 1.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.2)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    paperclip (4.3.6)
      activemodel (>= 3.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.2.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.5)
      mime-types
      mimemagic (= 0.3.0)
    parser (2.3.0.6)
      ast (~> 2.2)
    pg (0.18.4)
    polyamorous (1.3.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    powerpack (0.1.1)
    puma (3.2.0)
    rack (2.0.0.alpha)
      json
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (5.0.0.beta3)
      actioncable (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      actionmailer (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      actionview (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      activejob (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      activemodel (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      activerecord (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.alpha)
    rails-dom-testing (1.0.7)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0.beta, < 5.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6.0)
      rails-deprecated_sanitizer (>= 1.0.1)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    railties (5.0.0.beta3)
      actionpack (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      activesupport (= 5.0.0.beta3)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rainbow (2.1.0)
    rake (11.1.1)
    ransack (1.7.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      i18n
      polyamorous (~> 1.2)
    redis (3.2.2)
    responders (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.2.0, < 5.1)
    rspec-core (3.1.7)
      rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.1.2)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.1.3)
      rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
    rspec-rails (3.1.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.1.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.1.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.1.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.1.0)
    rspec-support (3.1.2)
    rubocop (0.38.0)
      parser (>= 2.3.0.6, < 3.0)
      powerpack (~> 0.1)
      rainbow (>= 1.99.1, < 3.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.1)
    ruby-progressbar (1.7.5)
    sass (3.4.21)
    sass-rails (5.0.4)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    shoulda-matchers (3.1.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
    simplecov (0.11.2)
      docile (~> 1.1.0)
      json (~> 1.8)
      simplecov-html (~> 0.10.0)
    simplecov-html (0.10.0)
    slim (3.0.6)
      temple (~> 0.7.3)
      tilt (>= 1.3.3, < 2.1)
    slim-rails (3.0.1)
      actionmailer (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
      railties (>= 3.1, < 5.0)
      slim (~> 3.0)
    sprockets (3.5.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.0.3)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sshkit (1.8.1)
      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)
    temple (0.7.6)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.5)
    tilt (2.0.2)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (3.0.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unicode-display_width (1.0.2)
    warden (1.2.6)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    websocket-driver (0.6.3)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  activeadmin!
  acts-as-taggable-on!
  airbrake (~> 4.3.4)
  awesome_print
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  bootstrap-sass
  byebug
  capistrano (~> 3.4)
  capistrano-bundler
  capistrano-rails
  capistrano-rvm
  coffee-rails
  config
  database_cleaner
  devise (= 4.0.0.rc2)
  factory_girl_rails
  jquery-rails
  kaminari!
  omniauth-facebook
  paperclip
  pg
  puma
  rails (= 5.0.0.beta3)
  redis
  rspec-rails
  rubocop
  sass-rails
  shoulda-matchers
  simplecov
  slim-rails
  uglifier

BUNDLED WITH
   1.11.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the dependencies for rspec-rails between 3.1.0 and 3.4.2, they've tightened up activesupport and actionpack:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/v3.1.0/rspec-rails.gemspec

and

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/v3.4.2/rspec-rails.gemspec

It looks like the currently beta'd 3.5 will support the 5.x line of those gems:

https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/v3.5.0.beta2/rspec-rails.gemspec